# Power query: split specific columns into seperate row

Tags: microsoft-excel, power-query

Not sure if the title really describes my problem and if Power Query is the right way to get this. My table contains events with individual IDs and invoices that belong to a certain ID:

| TYPE | ID | PROJECT | STATUS | Supplier | Invoice no. | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Event | 12345 | Project A | Open |  |  |  |
| Invoice | 12345 |  |  | Hotel | 123 | 100,00 |
| Invoice | 12345 |  |  | Hotel | 156 | 200,00 |
| Event | 45678 | Project B | Closed |  |  |  |
| Invoice | 45678 |  |  | Hotel | 456 | 100,00 |

Desired output but "Supplier - Invoice no. - Amount" should also be header rows or just formatted differently to separate it visually from data (didn't know how to show this with Tables which is probably already an answer to my question :D):

| ID | PROJECT | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | Project A | Open |
| Supplier | Invoice no. | Amount |
| Hotel | 123 | 100,00 |
| Hotel | 156 | 200,00 |

| ID | PROJECT | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 45678 | Project B | Closed |
| Supplier | Invoice no. | Amount |
| Hotel | 456 | 100,00 |

Is this possible with Power Query? If not, do I have to set up my table differently to make it work?

I'm completely new to Power Query and tried out lot of things, but I'm afraid I'm missing the basics to even know where to start.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. Please don't use images to show text information. Instead you can edit the question and post text representations. If you are unsure about formatting, someone else will correct it.

Comment: Thanks Rohit I edited my post!

Comment: Yeah nah, not in Power Query. I would load the table into Power BI and then use the Report Builder tool for that "invoice-style" layout.

Comment: Power Query can do the manipulation as shown in your tables, but will require you to use/learn the M language in the advance editor.

Comment: Thanks @MikeHoney, Power BI is new to me and sounds promising.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get the table results you show in Power Query using a custom aggregation with the `Table.Group` function.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"TYPE", type text}, {"ID", Int64.Type}, {"PROJECT", type text}, {"STATUS", type text}, {"Supplier", type text}, {"Invoice no.", Int64.Type}, {"Amount", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ID"}, {
        {"New Table", (t)=>
            let 
                #"ID" = {t[ID]{0},"Supplier"} &  List.RemoveFirstN(t[Supplier]),
                #"PROJECT" = {t[PROJECT]{0}, "Invoice no."} & List.RemoveNulls(t[#"Invoice no."]),
                #"STATUS" = {t[STATUS]{0}, "Amount"} & List.RemoveNulls(t[Amount]),
                #"Table" = Table.FromColumns(
                        {#"ID",#"PROJECT",#"STATUS"},
                        {"ID","PROJECT","STATUS"})
            in #"Table"
                }}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"ID"}),
    #"Expanded New Table" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "New Table", {"ID", "PROJECT", "STATUS"}, {"ID", "PROJECT", "STATUS"})
in
    #"Expanded New Table"
```

To obtain the differential formatting of the 2nd header row for each subsection, you can use Conditional Formatting in excel.

[image]